# How to run survival analysis in R with control variables?

Tags: r, cox-regression

In R I could use coxph from survival package to fit a Cox proportional hazard model on survival time (`time` and `event`)and the independent variable `stat`, but I'm not sure how to control for possible influence of, say, `pol`, other than just including it in the model as another independent variable. The following are the two models, one with and one without the control variable.

```
> colnames(first.data)
 [1] "state"           "year"            "event"           "time"          "contag_per"      "one_neigh_dis"  
 [7] "pol"         "demveto"         "dem_cont"        "tr.ma"           "stat"
> coxph = coxph(Surv(time, event) ~ stat, data = first.data, method = "breslow")
> summary(coxph)
Call:
coxph(formula = Surv(time, event) ~ stat, data = first.data, 
method = "breslow")

n= 48, number of events= 45 
(2 observations deleted due to missingness)

                  coef  exp(coef)   se(coef)      z Pr(>|z|)    
 stat -4.429e+01  5.835e-20  1.318e+01 -3.361 0.000777 ***
 ---
 Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

      exp(coef) exp(-coef) lower .95 upper .95
 stat 5.835e-20  1.714e+19 3.542e-31 9.612e-09

 Concordance= 0.708  (se = 0.059 )
 Rsquare= 0.239   (max possible= 0.997 )
 Likelihood ratio test= 13.12  on 1 df,   p=0.0002923
 Wald test            = 11.3  on 1 df,   p=0.000777
 Score (logrank) test = 11.77  on 1 df,   p=0.0006022
```

Second model with both independent (`stat`) and control variable (`pol`)

```
 > coxph = coxph(Surv(time, event) ~ stat + pol, data = first.data, method = "breslow")
 > summary(coxph)
Call:
coxph(formula = Surv(time, event) ~ stat + pol, 
    data = first.data, method = "breslow")

  n= 47, number of events= 44 
   (3 observations deleted due to missingness)

                      coef  exp(coef)   se(coef)      z Pr(>|z|)   
stat -4.121e+01  1.264e-18  1.341e+01 -3.072  0.00212 **
pol          3.778e+00  4.372e+01  1.745e+00  2.165  0.03042 * 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

                exp(coef) exp(-coef) lower .95 upper .95
stat 1.264e-18  7.911e+17 4.830e-30 3.308e-07
pol         4.372e+01  2.287e-02 1.429e+00 1.337e+03

Concordance= 0.746  (se = 0.059 )
Rsquare= 0.318   (max possible= 0.997 )
Likelihood ratio test= 17.99  on 2 df,   p=0.0001242
Wald test            = 14.29  on 2 df,   p=0.0007899
Score (logrank) test = 15.27  on 2 df,   p=0.0004833
```

What would be some other ideas to go about fitting cox proportional hazard model with control variables using the R survival package?

Comment: Please give us a minimum reproducible example as R code in the question to make it easier for us to help you. What have you tried so far?

Comment: @RYoda I included the control variable just as another independent variable in the model. But I'm not sure if that's the correct way to do it, and if there are other ways to do it.

Comment: +1 for the reproducible example, thx (and welcome at SO)! Your question is beyond my horizon, so let's wait and see for other answers :-)